# Built in function to convert list of numbers into list of binary numbers

Tags: core-language, binary

Does Mathematica have a build in way to convert a list of numbers into a list of binary numbers? If not how can this be accomplished?

Comment: There's `BaseForm` and `IntegerDigits`.

Comment: I think you should explain more clearly what exactly you mean with "list of binary numbers". You probably want to explain what you want to do with such a list...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 10]
```

> {65, 84, 31, 23, 72, 64, 29, 78, 43, 87}

```
BaseForm[#, 2] & /@ list
```

[image]

```
IntegerDigits[#, 2] & /@ list
```

> {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
>   {1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 
>   {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}}

```
FromDigits /@ %
```

> {1000001, 1010100, 11111, 10111, 1001000, 1000000, 11101, 1001110, \
>   101011, 1010111}

Comment: `BaseForm` and `IntegerDigits` are both listable.

Comment: @Karsten7. - Good point.